# print array without brackets

Tags: arrays, python-2.7

I have an array myarray with something like: [[ 10.54552827   0.10287327   0.21923103]]

I am using the csv.writer to output the array elements and an additional numeric variables e.q. cntr and n_obs both converted with str() to string output.

I have the code:

```
writer.writerow([cntr, n_obs, str(myarray)[2:-2]])
```

It removes the brackets, but does not insert the commas in the str(myarray)[2:-2] part.

How could I create this so I have 5 values (cntr, n_obs and the 3 array elements) as comma-delimited? Also, is there a way to format the array element values something like a float 10.6?

Comment: I am using python 2.7.

Comment: That's what `join()` is for. `','.join( myarrayWithStringValues )`

Comment: Not sure why but for the example I gave for myarray [[ 10.54552827 0.10287327 0.21923103]] it does not seem to work. Even tried: ', '.join(map(str, myarray)) to no avail. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried using `string.join()`?

```
myarray = [ 10.54552827, 0.10287327, 0.21923103 ]
rounded = ["%.2f" % i for i in myarray]

lst = [ cntr, n_obs ]
print ','.join( lst.extend(lst) )
```

I hope I'm interpreting your array correctly.

Comment: No, my array is exactly as I posted: [[ 10.54552827 0.10287327 0.21923103]] . 2 brackets on each side, no commas.

Comment: How is the sample initialized? I can understand if it's a list within a list.

Comment: I'm sorry, I interpreted your array as a list. So you're using actual arrays with `import array`? If so, then why not convert it into a list with `myarray.tolist()`?

Comment: the myarray.tolist() provides me with [[10.545528268232575, 0.1028732657157582, 0.21923103473652822]] ie. the commas but the join still does not seem to work because of the [[ and ]]. I think my issue is the double brackets...

Comment: So how is it initialized so I may start on the same foot as you?

Comment: myarray is a transposed matrix using numpy through a bunch of matrix algebra. The original arrays are structured arrays (actually record arrays). Is there a way to strip one set of the brackets and just make it a list?

Comment: Then `myarray.tolist()[0]` will be the list you want.

Comment: Thanks! Worked like a charm!